# Backbone / Marionette ItemView strategy

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, collectionview

I'm in the process of setting up a website with a blog that has some peculiarities. It's sort of a tumblr-esque experience, where there's different post-type:

- Facebook-post
- Quote
- Article
- Research

These posts share some common attributes such as `id`, `title`, `post_date`, `post_url_slug`, but some have a `post_image` or `post_external_link` for example. This is all dependent on the `post_type`, which can hold values such as `facebook`, `quote`, `article` etc. What would be a good strategy to determine which type it is when rendering a `Marionette.CollectionView` and either selecting a different tempalte altogether or handling this in the template with underscore's arbitrary javascript in my template? Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely don't put the logic in the view template. That will lead to pain, suffering, hate and the dark side. :P

You can override the `getItemView` method on the CollectionView or CompositeView and use that to determine which view type you want. https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/marionette.collectionview.js#L122

```
var Stuff = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  // ...,

  getItemView: function(item){
    var type = item.get("whatever_field");
    var viewType;
    if (type === "some value"){
      viewType = SomeViewType;
    } else {
      viewType = AnotherViewType;
    }
    return viewType;
  }
});
```

Comment: This way you can have different behaviors in the views, not only different templates and avoid having events in the view that only make sense for a type or, even worst, a bunch of if statements in each event handler to have different implementations based on type. My 2 cents...

Comment: I think that solution just adds more lines of code where it doesn't need to. An itemview handles one model, how different could the behavior be before you need a different model? If its the same model just with different events and pieces of HTML you should definitely use the same ItemView with different templates. The events that don't apply to each model type will be ignored if you do the selectors correctly.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing in the answer, but instead of using a switch case use requirejs inside of the getItemView method to pull in the corresponding file which returns the correct ItemView? I've tried this but it seems there is a timing issue where getItemView executes and returns undefined before the require statement of the itemView can return the view to return in the method. Just wondering if anyone else had tried the same and succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

You should have one single ItemView, don't need to override getItemView of the CollectionView. The ItemView should be the one in charge of deciding the template to use, that's what getTemplate is for. It should look like this:

```
var MyItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    getTemplate: function() {
        var template;
        switch(this.model.get('type')) {
            case 'facebook':
                template = 'Template for Facebook type';
                break;
            case 'quote':
                template = 'Template for Quote type';
                break;
            case 'article':
                template = 'Template for Article type';
                break;
        }
        return template;
    }
});
```

This way you only have one ItemView for the one model you have and the rendering decisions are left to the template as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this in the ItemView intialize function and switch the template there. So long as you are planning to use the same events cross post type

Comment: Well the events are identical, but the link to detailview may not be present for all items. That shouldn't be a problem though right?